# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'children' of '_ref' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Login Form which uses React-Context, but when i debug, there was an error : "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'children' of '_ref' as it is undefined." in file "UserContext.js"
Please tell me what is the issue here and what should be done. Thank you very much

file **UserContext.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import React from "react";
import { getUserAccount } from "../components/service/userService";

const UserContext =  React.createContext({ name: '', auth: false });
const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // User is the name of the "data" that gets stored in context
  const userDefault={
    isLoading: "true",
    isAuthenticate: false,
    token: "",
    account: {}
  }
  const [user, setUser] = useState(userDefault);

  // Login updates the user data with a name parameter
  const loginContext = (userData) => {
    setUser({ ...userData, isLoading: false });
    
  };

  // Logout updates the user data to default
  const logout = () => {
    setUser((user) => ({
      name: '',
      auth: false,
    }));
  };
  const fetchUser = async () => {
    let response = await getUserAccount()
    console.log(33,response);
    if (response && response.data.errorcode == 0) {
      let groupWithRole = response.data.data.groupWithRole
      let email = response.data.data.email
      let username = response.data.data.username
      let token = response.data.data.access_token

      let data = {
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthenticate: true,
        token: token,
        account: { groupWithRole, email, username },

      }
      console.log(44,data);
      setUser(data)
    }
    else {
      setUser({ ...userDefault, isLoading: false });

    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.pathname !== '/' || window.location.pathname!=='login') {
      fetchUser()
    }
  },[])
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, loginContext, logout }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
export { UserContext, UserProvider }
```

file **App.js**

```
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.scss';
import Nav from './components/navigation/Nav';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './components/login/login';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Register from './components/register/register';
import User from './components/user/user';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import _ from 'lodash';
import AppRoutes from './components/routes/AppRoutes';
import { Audio } from 'react-loader-spinner'
import { UserContext } from './context/UserContext';
import { useContext } from 'react';
function App() {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log(24, user);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        {user && user.isLoading == true ? <Audio
          heigth="100"
          width="100"
          color='grey'
          ariaLabel='loading'
        /> : <>
          <div className='appHeader'>
            <Nav />
          </div>
          <div className='app-container'>
            <AppRoutes />
          </div></>}

      </Router>
      <ToastContainer
        position="bottom-center"
        autoClose={5000}
        hideProgressBar={false}
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
        theme="light"
      />
      {/* Same as */}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

file ***index.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {UserProvider} from './context/UserContext'
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <UserProvider>
    <App />
  </UserProvider>,
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Where do you use `UserProvider`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski  I use in file index.js, i've added to my post